# How to calculate hours active between two timestamps

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, timestamp, apache-spark-sql

If I have a Dataframe with two `Timestamps`, called 'start' and 'end', how can I calculate a list of all the hour's between 'start' and 'end'?

Another say to say this might be "which hours was the record active"?

For example:

```
// Input
|              start|                end|
|2017-06-01 09:30:00|2017-06-01 11:30:00|
|2017-06-01 14:00:00|2017-06-01 14:30:00|

// Result
|              start|                end|hours_active|
|2017-06-01 09:30:00|2017-06-01 11:30:00|   (9,10,11)|
|2017-06-01 14:00:00|2017-06-01 14:30:00|        (14)|
```

Thanks

Comment: How would you process the case when the date is not same and hours overlap, for example `start=2017-06-01 09:30:00`  and `end=2017-06-02 11:30:00`? Which should be the value of `hours_active` and does it make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the difference between the start and end is always less than 24 hours, you can use the following `UDF`. Assuming the type of the columns is `Timestamp`:

```
val getActiveHours = udf((s: Long, e: Long) => {
  if (e >= s) {
    val diff = e - s
    (s to (s+diff)).toSeq
  } else {
    // the end is in the next day
    (s to 24).toSeq ++ (1L to e).toSeq 
  }
})

df.withColumn("hours_active", getActiveHours(hour($"start"), hour($"end")))
```

Using the example data in the question gives:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+------------+
|start                |end                  |hours_active|
+---------------------+---------------------+------------+
|2017-06-01 09:30:00.0|2017-06-01 11:30:00.0|[9, 10, 11] |
|2017-06-01 14:00:00.0|2017-06-01 14:30:00.0|[14]        |
+---------------------+---------------------+------------+
```

---

**Note:** For larger differences between the timestamps the above code can be adjusted to take that into account. It would then be necessary to look at other fields in addition to the hour, e.g. day/month/year.